# CSS - reset animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, reset

I have an issue with animation created using css. Everything is working fine, I just need to finish this and **set input type to reset animation.**

Here is my css that should reset animation:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
var heading = $('h1').clone().removeClass();
$('h1').remove();
$('header').append(heading);
$('h1').addClass('fadein_element');
```

});

CSS animation

```
@keyframes fadein {
0%   { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 1; }
enter code here

.fadein{-webkit-animation: fadein 3s ease-in ;
            -moz-animation: fadein 3s ease-in ;
             animation: fadein 3s ease-in ;
```

This was my basic html for that part:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" checked="checked" id="st-control-1"/>
<a href="#st-panel-1">WebGear</a>
```

And here is the edited one:

```
input type="radio" name="radio-set" checked="checked" id="st-control-1"/>
<a href="#st-panel-1"><h1 class="fadein_element"><button class="fadein_element">WebGear</button></h1></a>
```

I got lost in it and nothing resets the animation. Other than that it works fine.To sum it up, do you guys have any ideas how to get this working ? Preferably with default html code...

**Edit: Posting a minimal code wich I am trying to get working**

```
</head>
<body>
<div class="st-container">

<input type="radio" name="radio-set" checked="checked" id="st-control-1"/>
<a href="#st-panel-1">Something</a>

<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-2"/>
<a href="#st-panel-2">Happiness</a>

<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-3"/>
<a href="#st-panel-3">Tranquillity</a>

<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-4"/>
<a href="#st-panel-4">Positivity</a>

<input type="radio"  name="radio-set" id="st-control-5"/>
<a href="#st-panel-5"> WebGear</a>

<div class="st-scroll">

    <section class="st-panel" id="st-panel-5">
        <div class="st-deco" data-icon="H"></div>
<div id="section1"> 
<div id="menu"> <img id="menuitem" src="Images/Menuitem.png"/>
<div id="hlava">
<div id="flashContent">
---Here goes the content---
There are just closing tags
```

And CSS

```
@keyframes fadein {
0%   { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 1; }
}
.fadein{-webkit-animation: fadein 3s ease-in ;
            -moz-animation: fadein 3s ease-in ;
             animation: fadein 3s ease-in ;
```

Once I click on "radio button" I want my (in this case st-panel-5) to reset animation. Any of those 5 buttons will do that so I belive I could apply that to class st-panel.

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet that reproduces the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you set all but the checked radio input's targeted `st-panel` to `display: none; opacity: 0`, and then set `animation: fadein ...;` to the checked radio input's targeted `st-panel-nn` id.

Than
*Click the 2 first radio inputs to check the behavior*

```css
#st-control-1:checked ~ .st-scroll .st-panel:not(#st-panel-1),
#st-control-2:checked ~ .st-scroll .st-panel:not(#st-panel-2) {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

#st-control-1:checked ~ .st-scroll #st-panel-1,
#st-control-2:checked ~ .st-scroll #st-panel-2 {
  animation: fadein 1.5s ease-in;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="st-container">

  <input type="radio" name="radio-set" checked="checked" id="st-control-1"/>
  <a href="#st-panel-1">Something</a>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-2"/>
  <a href="#st-panel-2">Happiness</a>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-3"/>
  <a href="#st-panel-3">Tranquillity</a>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-4"/>
  <a href="#st-panel-4">Positivity</a>

  <input type="radio"  name="radio-set" id="st-control-5"/>
  <a href="#st-panel-5"> WebGear</a>

  <div class="st-scroll">

    <section class="st-panel" id="st-panel-1">
      <div class="st-deco" data-icon="H"></div>
      <div id="section1"> 
        <div id="menu"> <img id="menuitem" src="Images/Menuitem.png"/>
          <div id="hlava">
            <div id="flashContent">
            Some content 1
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>          
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="st-panel" id="st-panel-2">
      <div class="st-deco" data-icon="H"></div>
      <div id="section1"> 
        <div id="menu"> <img id="menuitem" src="Images/Menuitem.png"/>
          <div id="hlava">
            <div id="flashContent">
            Some content 2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>          
      </div>
    </section>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @Filip5 Sounds perfect ... I will update my answer's text a little and looking forward for your accept.

Comment: You Sir, are amazing. I am styling those buttons now and so far it is working. You saved me lot of trouble

Comment: @Filip5 Thanks, and I'm glad I were able to do that

Answer (score 0):

"Here is my css that should reset animation:" - it's actually Javascript - jQuery, but maybe I misunderstood.

After an animation is executed use this code:
`element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;`

but I think it's pure Javascript (without jQuery) so in your example it would be:
`document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].offsetWidth = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].offsetWidth`

You can find more information [here](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/).

Comment: @dunnohpwishouldnamemyself

I've tried your solutions and the ones on the link you provided, but it doesn't work for me. I might be doing something wrong hovewer...

Comment: The one I described in my answer definitely worked for me! I hope you'll get your code run soon